# How to read/print the ( _io.TextIOWrapper) data?

Tags: python, printing, io, typeerror, word-wrap

With the following code I want to > open a file > read the contents and strip the non-required lines > then write the data to the file and also read the file for downstream analyses.

```
with open("chr2_head25.gtf", 'r') as f,\
    open('test_output.txt', 'w+') as f2:
    for lines in f:
        if not lines.startswith('#'):
            f2.write(lines)
    f2.close()
```

Now, I want to read the f2 data and do further processing in pandas or other modules but I am running into a problem while reading the data(`f2`).

```
data = f2 # doesn't work
print(data) #gives
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test_output.txt' mode='w+' encoding='UTF-8'>

data = io.StringIO(f2)  # doesn't work
# Error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/everestial007/PycharmProjects/stitcher/pHASE-Stitcher-Markov/markov_final_test/phase_to_vcf.py", line 64, in <module>
data = io.StringIO(f2)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Comment: Can you please be specific. I tried doing `f2.read()` on the second line of the code while `open(...) as f2.read()`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The file is already closed (when the previous `with` block finishes), so you cannot do anything more to the file. To reopen the file, create another with statement and use the `read` attribute to read the file.

```
with open('test_output.txt', 'r') as f2:
    data = f2.read()
    print(data)
```

Comment: I tried not putting `f2.close()` at the end of that for loop, but it didn't work either. I already know what you have suggested. I just didn't wanted to read the file again and again. Was wondering if that codes is missing something.

Comment: @everestial007: The `f2.close()` is redundant because the preceding  `with` does it automatically.

Comment: How can I convert `f2` to an `str` object ?

Comment: @Leevo `data` is the str object of the file’s content.

Comment: @abccd how this answer is using io.TextIOWrapper ?

Comment: Well the person asking forgot to read from the file handler. So he was trying to read using the wrong object.