# Dict has no attribute write() on json

Tags: python, json, io, attributeerror

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'write'
```

It happens on `json.dump(data, config_file, indent=4)`

```
import json


def get_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)


def write_json(path, data):
    config_file = get_json(path)
    json.dump(data, config_file, indent=4)
    config_file.close()



def lines_to_dict(linesUp):
    lines = []
    for line in linesUp:
        lines.append(line.split(':'))
    return dict(lines)
```

I dont understand why i have an error like this?
How can i modify this code?

TraceBack :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\quent\PycharmProjects\testSpinergie\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    update_config("./ressource/fileconf.json", "./ressource/changes.txt")
  File "C:\Users\quent\PycharmProjects\testSpinergie\main.py", line 10, in update_config
    json_util.write_json(pathConfig, dictUp)
  File "C:\Users\quent\PycharmProjects\testSpinergie\utils\json_util.py", line 11, in write_json
    json.dump(data, config_file, indent=4)
  File "C:\Users\quent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 180, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Thanks for helpers !

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback?

Comment: ``json.dump`` expects a file-like object as second argument - and you're passing in a dict. [See docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: `config_file = get_json(path)` gets a json data which you then try to write *to* by `json.dump(data, config_file, indent=4)` - that is not going to work ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open new file to write

Here is the example:

```py
import json

def get_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)

def write_json(path, data):
    with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as config_file:
        json.dump(data, config_file, indent=4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = get_json('input.json')
    write_json('output.json', data)
```

Take a look at line:

```py
with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as config_file:
```

Comment: A brief explaination about I/O in Python would be useful for the OP I guess, anyway well done, +1

Answer (score 1):

```
json.dump(data, config_file, indent=4)
```

This function [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) expects an `object` as the first argument, and a [`_io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) as the second argument.

---

You are passing `config_file` instead, which is the result of `get_json()`, which returns a `dict`.

---

Maybe you wanted something like this:

```
config_file = open(path, 'w')
json.dump(data, config_file, indent=4)
config_file.close()
```

or (even better):

```
with open(path, 'w') as config_file:
    json.dump(data, config_file, indent=4)
```

---

To better understand how does Python's `I`/`O` system work, I would suggest to read [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438303/how-to-read-print-the-io-textiowrapper-data).

Comment: Ok i understand why now, thanks for your time

Comment: Nothing, remember to accept an answer if it worked :)